# Bad voltage at second breaker box

Tags: voltage

I got 109 on one leg and 140 on the other. Have tried to run only one leg but voltage remains the same. The main box is 120 at each leg

Comment: Unhook one of the hot wires (intentionally disabling one of the legs).   I bet the problem becomes apparent: a lost neutral.

Comment: Do these voltages change when you turn things on and off at the 2nd breaker panel?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.